# Independence of Events and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

A person tried by a 3-judge panel is declared guilty if at least 2 judges cast votes of guilty. Suppose that when the defendant is in fact guilty, each judge will independently vote guilty with probability 0.7, whereas when the defendant is in fact innocent, this probability drops to 0.2. Assume 70 percent of defendants are guilty.

1. Let Ei, i = 1, 2, 3 denote the event that judge i casts a guilty vote. Are these events independent? Explain
2. Are Ei’s, i = 1, 2, 3, conditionally independent? Explain.
3. Compute the conditional probability that judge number 3 votes guilty given that judges 1 and 2 vote guilty.

I am honestly stuck on where to even start with this problem. I would assume that the events are independent because the problem states it as such.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that the events are independent.  It says that the judges vote independently, meaning they don't know in advance how the others vote.  However, if you know that Judge A voted guilty then it's more likely that Judge B did also than if Judge A voted not guilty.  (Why?)  So the events are not independent.

Comment: OK, perhaps I don't understand independence too well, but if they don't know each other's vote then doesn't that mean that they don't influence each other?

Comment: Yes, it does, but independence of events in probability is a different idea.  If you think of the probability as an estimate of the likelihood of an event, then an intuitive way of thinking about independence is that knowing whether or not one of the events occurs doesn't influence our estimate of the likelihood of the other.  Suppose Judge A wears a red tie with probability $.6$ and a blue tie with probability $.4$ and that his tie color doesn't influence his vote in any way.  The events "Judge A is wearing a red tie" and "Judge B votes guilty" really are independent.

Comment: I suppose, my question really is, is there a way to prove this with equations or do I simply need to explain with words?

Comment: By definition, two events $A,B$ are independent if and only if $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$  This is how you have to prove or disprove independence.  The comments I made were intuitive, and have no probative value.

Comment: Well, I'm going to go with the idea that the votes of each individual judge are independent from each other. What I've understood from you and the question, the event that any given judge votes guilty is dependent on whether the defendant is guilty and nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93596/discussion-between-thrmsnprfs-and-saulspatz).

Answer (score 1):

I will just do the first part, because the other parts are similar.

You want to find the probability that $J_3$ votes guilty given the info that $J_1$ and $J_2$ votes guilty, and for this, we first need the probability that $J_1$ and $J_2$ even votes guilty in the first place.

Let $J_{ig}$ denote the event that judge $i$ votes guilty.  Let $G$ denote the event that the defendant is guilty.

\begin{align}
P(J_{1g}, J_{2g})&=P(J_{1g}, J_{2g}\mid G)\,P(G)+P(J_{1g}, J_{2g}\mid G^\complement)\,P(G^\complement) \\
&=\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{2}{10}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{71}{200}
\end{align}

Moving on to the required probability:
\begin{align}
P(J_{3g}\mid J_{1g}, J_{2g})&=\dfrac{P(J_{3g}, J_{1g}, J_{2g}\mid G)\,P(G)+P(J_{3g}, J_{1g}, J_{2g}\mid G^\complement)\,P(G^\complement)}{P(J_{1g}, J_{2g})}\\
&=\dfrac{\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^3\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{10}\right)^3\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)}{\frac{71}{200}}\\
&=\dfrac{97}{142}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 1 is no.

$$P(E_i)=P(E_i|G)P(G)+P(E_i|I)P(I)=\frac{7}{10}\frac{7}{10}+\frac{2}{10}\frac{3}{10}=\frac{55}{100}$$

$$P(E_1E_2E_3)=P(E_1E_2E_3|G)P(G)+P(E_1E_2E_3|I)P(I)=\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^3\frac{7}{10}+\left(\frac{2}{10}\right)^3\frac{3}{10}=\frac{2425}{10000}$$

And by the definition of independence, we have

$$P(E_1E_2E_3)\ne P(E_1)P(E_2)P(E_3)$$

The answer to 2 is no as the definition of conditional independence is

$$P((E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)|G)=P(E_1|G)P(E_2|G)P(E_3|G)$$

We **don't** have

$$P(E_i|G)=P(E_i)$$

so, except for coincidence

$$P(E_1|G)P(E_2|G)P(E_3|G)\ne P(E_1)P(E_2)P(E_3)$$

and therefore

$$P((E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)|G)\ne P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$$

For 3, $P(E_1E_2)=\frac{7}{10}\frac{7}{10}\frac{7}{10}+\frac{3}{10}\frac{2}{10}\frac{2}{10}=\frac{355}{1000}$.

Also $P(E_1E_2|E_3)P(E_3)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)-P(E_1+E_2)$, by conditional probability.

$P(E_1+E_2)=P(E_1E_2)+P(E_1E_2')+P(E_1'E_2)=\frac{355}{1000}+2\frac{195}{1000}=\frac{745}{1000}$.

$$P(E_1E_2|E_3)P(E_3)=\frac{355}{1000}$$

So

$$P(E_3|E_1E_2)=\frac{P(E_1E_2|E_3)P(E_3)}{P(E_1E_2)}=\frac{355}{745}=\frac{71}{149}$$